# How do i add first and last elements of a list and pop them , and do this for the whole list in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make a love calculator. For that i take two names and add "loves" between those name. split the whole string into characters. make a directory  with number of times a characters repeats in the list as value.

Now i need to add the first and last elements in the list of value and append the sum in other_list. And do this in loop till i have only two  digits in `list_of_numbers` .
I am having problem in the loop part.
can please someone help me . Thank you

```
name1 = input("Hey please enter first name here\n")
name2 = input("Hey please enter second name here\n")
love = "loves"

final_string = name1 + love + name2
list_of_name = list(final_string)

numbers = {}

for lets in list_of_name:
    if lets not in numbers:
        numbers[lets] = 1
    else:
        numbers[lets] += 1

list_of_numbers = list(numbers.values())

other_list = []
i = len(list_of_numbers)
print(list_of_numbers)

"""this is where i am having problem"""
if len(list_of_numbers) != 2;
    for x in range(0, i, 2):
        a = int(list_of_numbers[0]) + int(list_of_numbers[-1])
        other_list.append(a)
        list_of_numbers.pop()
        list_of_numbers.pop(0)
        print(list_of_numbers)
        print(other_list)
list_of_numbers += other_list
print(list_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your code should output, but you should check the length within the for loop.

```
for x in range(0, i, 2):
    if len(list_of_numbers) < 2: # check here
        break
    a = int(list_of_numbers[0]) + int(list_of_numbers[-1])
    other_list.append(a)
    list_of_numbers.pop()
    list_of_numbers.pop(0)
    print(list_of_numbers)
    print(other_list)
list_of_numbers += other_list
print(list_of_numbers)
```

Running this worked.

```
name1 = input("Hey please enter first name here\n")
name2 = input("Hey please enter second name here\n")
love = "loves"

final_string = name1 + love + name2
list_of_name = list(final_string)

numbers = {}

for lets in list_of_name:
    if lets not in numbers:
        numbers[lets] = 1
    else:
        numbers[lets] += 1

list_of_numbers = list(numbers.values())

other_list = []
i = len(list_of_numbers)
print(list_of_numbers)

"""this is where i am having problem"""
for x in range(0, i, 2):
    if len(list_of_numbers) < 2:
        break
    a = int(list_of_numbers[0]) + int(list_of_numbers[-1])
    other_list.append(a)
    list_of_numbers.pop()
    list_of_numbers.pop(0)
    print(list_of_numbers)
    print(other_list)
list_of_numbers += other_list
print(list_of_numbers)
```

Full code that doesn't give any error.

Comment: Hey, there's a runtime error at ```list_of_numbers.pop(0)``` (Index error : pop from empty list)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify why are you skipping 2 steps `for x in range(0,i,2)` ? else I think if you only want first element and last element of the list till the list is left with 2 elements, there is no need to skip 2 elements, you can use `while` loop.

```
while(len(list_of_numbers) > 2):
        a = int(list_of_numbers[0]) + int(list_of_numbers[-1])
        other_list.append(a)
        list_of_numbers.pop()
        list_of_numbers.pop(0)
        print(list_of_numbers)
        print(other_list)
list_of_numbers += other_list
print(list_of_numbers)
```

I have updated your code based on the problem. Here, I have used `OrderedDict()` for the correct sum and have changed the logic inside the loop, to correctly capture the scenarios like when there are more than 1 element in the list and when there is just 1 element left in the list.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
name1 = input("Hey please enter first name here\n")
name2 = input("Hey please enter second name here\n")
love = "loves"

final_string = name1 + love + name2
list_of_name = list(final_string)

numbers = OrderedDict()

for lets in list_of_name:
    if lets not in numbers:
        numbers[lets] = 1
    else:
        numbers[lets] += 1

list_of_numbers = list(numbers.values())
print(list_of_numbers)

other_list = []
i = len(list_of_numbers)
print(list_of_numbers)

"""this is where i am having problem"""
while(list_of_numbers):
    if(len(list_of_numbers) == 1):
        other_list.append(list_of_numbers.pop())
    else:
        a = int(list_of_numbers[0]) + int(list_of_numbers[-1])
        other_list.append(a)
        list_of_numbers.pop()
        list_of_numbers.pop(0)
    
    if(len(list_of_numbers) == 0):
        #print(len(list_of_numbers))
        list_of_numbers += other_list
        other_list.clear()
        if (len(list_of_numbers)==2):
            print(list_of_numbers)
            break
        
print("%2d%2d" % (list_of_numbers[0],list_of_numbers[1]))
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/oFsLVG7EAZ4 can you please check this link out. i am trying to code this out . thank you.

Comment: @Mariya I have updated your code based on the problem